# Cannot read span elements

Tags: ruby, webdriver, watir

Hi since I did gem install watir watir-classic my scripts are not reading anymore the span elements. Can you please help me to fix this problem

here my example

**Source**

```
Rented&nbsp;
<SPAN class="displayData" style="padding-left:2px; width: 15;"><span name="tab4RateInfoForm.vehicleGroup"/>F</span></SPAN>&nbsp;
```

**My code**

```
carGroup=browser.span(:name => 'tab4RateInfoForm.vehicleGroup').text
```

**Error message**

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.3.0/lib/watir-classic/locator.rb:79:in `rescue in match?': name is an unknown way of finding a <span> element (tab4RateInfoForm.vehicleGroup) (Watir::Exception::MissingWayOfFindingObjectException)
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.3.0/lib/watir-classic/locator.rb:76:in `match?'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.3.0/lib/watir-classic/locator.rb:62:in `block in match_with_specifiers?'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.3.0/lib/watir-classic/locator.rb:59:in `each'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.3.0/lib/watir-classic/locator.rb:59:in `all?'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.3.0/lib/watir-classic/locator.rb:59:in `match_with_specifiers?'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.3.0/lib/watir-classic/locator.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in each'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.3.0/lib/watir-classic/locator.rb:140:in `block in each_element'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.3.0/lib/watir-classic/locator.rb:139:in `each'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.3.0/lib/watir-classic/locator.rb:139:in `each_element'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.3.0/lib/watir-classic/locator.rb:21:in `block in each'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.3.0/lib/watir-classic/locator.rb:20:in `each'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.3.0/lib/watir-classic/locator.rb:20:in `each'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.3.0/lib/watir-classic/locator.rb:150:in `locate'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.3.0/lib/watir-classic/element.rb:33:in `locate'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.3.0/lib/watir-classic/element.rb:63:in `assert_exists'
from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.3.0/lib/watir-classic/element.rb:132:in `text'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1: Use css locator**

You will have to use a css-locator (or xpath):

```
carGroup = browser.span(:css, 'span[name="tab4RateInfoForm.vehicleGroup"]').text
```

**Solution 2: Monkey patch**

Alternatively, if you have a lot of legacy scripts that use the name attribute, you can monkey patch Watir to have the name method for all elements (or specific element if desired).

Add the following to wherever you require watir:

```
Watir::IE.new(true)
module Watir
  class Element
    def name
      return self.attribute_value('name')
    end
  end
end
```

Your original method should now work.

Comment: Solution 1: Use css locator didn't work 

Solution 2: Monkey patch It works realy well Just added a new class `class Element
    def name
      return self.attribute_value('name')
    end
  end
` into **Locator.rb**  and all the scripts are working thanks again

Comment: Solution 1 needed quotes for the attribute value. Answer updated.

Comment: Before monkey patching i would change your html to be valid - name is not a valid attribute for span element in html. I would access that span like this `browser.span(:class => "displayData").span.text` or like this `browser.span(:text => "F")`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `span` elements can no longer be accessed via `name` attribute.

Try this (use generic `element` instead of `span`):

```
carGroup=browser.element(:name => 'tab4RateInfoForm.vehicleGroup').text
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. Do I need to udate anything else? **Here the error Message** `C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.3.0/lib/watir-classic/locator.rb:79:in `rescue in match?': name is an unknown way of finding a <*> element (tab4RateInfoForm.vehicleGroup) (Watir::Exception::MissingWayOfFindingObjectException) from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.3.0/lib/watir-classic/locator.rb:76:in `match?' from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.3.0/lib/watir-classic/locator.rb:62:in `block in match_with_specifiers?'

Comment: Looks like you found a solution.